# #define returns a wrong number in C

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to this very basic task in C, where I want to define a number of ints in a header file. I've done this like so:

```
#define MINUTE (60)
#define HOUR   (60 * MINUTE)
#define DAY    (24 * HOUR)
```

The problem is that while MINUTE and HOUR return the correct answer, DAY returns something weird.

```
Serial.println(MINUTE); // 60
Serial.println(HOUR); // 3600
Serial.println(DAY); // 20864
```

Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Let me guess: You have 16 bit `int`?

Comment: I've updated the question so that you can see what im doing. In short by outputting the defines directly i get the commented out result

Comment: Is this a program for Arduino? If so, its `int` is 16-bit long and 86400 is too large to store in it.

Comment: Yes im using Arduino and sorry for claiming it was C (i thought so). Makes sense that the reason is that its a 16 bit int and therefore too large. Thanks for the quick assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have something like

```
int days = DAY;
```

or

```
unsigned days = DAY;
```

You seem to have 16 bit integers. The max. representable positive value for (signed) 2s complement integers with 16 bits is 32767, for unsigned it is 65535.

So , as `24 * 3600 == 86400`, you invoke undefined behaviour for the signed `int` and wrap for the `unsigned` (the `int` will likely wrap, too, but that is not guaranteed).

This results in `86400 modulo 65356` (which is 2 to the power of 16) which happens to be `20864`.

Solution: use `stdint.h` types: `uint32_t` or `int32_t` to get defined sized integers.

Edit: Using function arguments follows basically the same principle as the initialisers above.

Update: As you clamed, when directly passing the integr constant `86400` to the function, this will have type `long`, because the compiler will automatically choose the smallest type which can hold the values. It is very likely that the `println` methods are overloaded for `long` arguments, so they will print the correct value.

However, for the expression the original types are relevant. And all values `24`, `60`, `60` will have `int` type, so the result will also be `int`. The compiler will not use a larger type, just because the result **might** overflow. Use `24L` and you will get a `long` result for the macros, too.

Comment: This does make we wonder though. I can swap out `#define DAY                     (24 * HOUR)` with `#define DAY (86400)` and then it works fine. Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you actually managed to dig up an ancient 16 bit compiler (where did you find it? ) Otherwise I'd like to see the code that produces these numbers.

Comment: Surprisingly, there are still 8 and 16 bit CPUs around (actually, they still outnumber the 32 bit CPUs). So the term "ancient" seems a bit missplaced.

Comment: Well, horrifically there are still schools that use Turbo C to teach their programming classes because ...  well, basically for no good reason.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: While I agree about banning that ancient compiler on Desktop platforms, generally assuming `int` is 32 bits (in both directions: there are/were platforms with 64 bit `int) is also a very bad idea and one of the reasons so many C programs fail spectacularily.

Comment: Look at the tag: Arduino. 16-bit processors, mostly.

Comment: @Olaf Agree at least 100s of millions of embedded processors are made each year (2015) using C with 16-bit `int`.

Comment: @chux: I'd assume one wo two decades more, but who's counting :-) (How many smartphones alone are soled per year? How many washing machines, cars, toasters, etc)

Answer (score 0):

20864 = 86400 % 65536

Try storing the value in an int instead of a short.

Comment: Why do you assume OP uses `short`? The functions do take an `int` (or `unsigned`).

Comment: Not assuming, suggesting.  The result produced is exactly what I expect if the value is stored in a short.  There could be many reasons, but without seeing more code, it's hard to know for certain.

Comment: "... in an int instead of a short." Sounds like assuming. Note that on Arduino `int` has 16 bits (identical to `short` on that platform). The C and C++ standards very well allows 16 bit `int` - as well as 128 bit `short`.